# Debug the obfuscated stack trace for Android using ProGuard

Tags: android, android-proguard

I have been trying to obfuscate my Android app stack trace using ProGuard mapping file. I have tried using `-verbose` and added these lines in configuration file `proguard-rules.pro` in Android Studio also:

```
-renamesourcefileattribute SourceFile
-keepattributes SourceFile,LineNumberTable
```

But still instead of line numbers there appearing `Unknown Source` while using `retrace.sh -verbose`.

Any idea why line numbers are not appearing?

Answer (score 5):

I decode my obfuscate stack trace like this:

In your sdk directory `android-sdk\tools\proguard\bin\` .. open console and write: `retrace.bat -verbose mapping.txt obfuscated_trace.txt` 
Where `mapping.txt` is generated from android studio when apk is build for release, and `obfuscated_trace.txt` is your exception from google play console.

and it works for me. Hope to help!

Comment: In my case it's still appearing `Unknown Source` instead of line number.

Comment: hmm intresting.. because i even test it again before write you here and for me everything works fine..

Comment: Now Android Studio uses `R8`, there is no proguard in Android SDK